# Дамп БД через mysqldump и phpmyadmin отличия

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, dump

Дамп БД, сделанных через mysqldump, командой

```
mysqldump -u user -p12345 --single-transaction dbname
```

и БД, экспортированная через phpmyadmin, отличаются, как по размеру, где разница не так значительна, в контексте общего размера базы, в несколько сотен килобайт, так и по коду соответственно.

**Вопрос:** значительны ли это различия, если, например, дамп сделан чз консоль mysqldump, а импорт делать через интерфейс phpmyadmin, возможны ли какие то ошибки в работе сайта с такой БД?

Comment: Отличаться могут. В одном может быть блоки типа drop if exists, к примеру, а в другом - попросту отсутствовать. Ну и другие тоже . Можно просто сравнить эти два текстовых файла в редакторе и понять разницу.

Comment: @void да, но вопрос в том, могут ли возникнуть проблемы при использовании разных способов импорта и экспорта